# Is this NSDictionary valid the way it is set up? Using XML to NSDictionary plugin

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, key, nsdictionary

I'm using the XMLReader plugin found here https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary to convert my XML data into an NS-Dictionary, but I am confused by how the dictionary is being set up.  Here is what I am given:

```
 {
     response =     {
         "@status" = ok;
         authentication =         {
             "@description" = "The username you provided is valid.";
             "@login" = USERNAME;
             "@response" = success;
             "@user_id" = USERID;
         };
     };
 }
```

I am trying to take the response object and say if key is equal to success then do something, but I'm not sure if this dictionary is even set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the weirdness of the @names as keys, it seems valid.

You could easily ask for your element response ( `[  objectForKey:@"response"]` ), get the `[   objectForKey:@"authentication"]` and then `[   objectForKey:@"@response"]` to check `[yourString isEqualToString:@"success"]`.

Edit: Adding example

I've recently noticed some ; where commas should have been, but let's hope that's just a typo or something like it.

In case you have a doubt, you can always `NSLog(@"%@", [yourFirstDictionary allKeys]);` to make sure those are valid keys.

Let's call your first object `myDict` for the sake of the example.

```
NSDictionary * response = [myDict objectForKey:@"response"]; // this should have @status and authentication as keys
NSDictionary * authentication = [response objectForKey:@"authentication"];
NSString * innerResponse = [authentication objectForKey:@"@response"];

if ([innerResponse isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Ok so that seems to be working.  When I do `[ objectForKey:@"authentication"]` I get null so I started with `[ objectForKey:@"response"]`, but then how do I move down to the next one (authentication?)

Comment: It's kind of confusing because response is wrapped in authentication is wrapped in response...

Comment: Given that the main object is a dictionary itself you should start with [ objectForKey:@"response"], before moving on. And then on the second response ask for [ objectForKey@"@response"];

Comment: `[ objectForKey:@"authentication"]` is still giving me null.  I'm not sure how to code that correctly in reference to the main object.  Would you mind writing out an example?

Comment: awesome.  thanks for the example.  I didn't realize the main object, etc. had to be NSDictionaries